# UnsupportedEncodingException when I moved logic to my own class from my Servlet doPost method

Tags: java, servlets

When I have this code in my servlet doPost method, everything is fine.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
...
String data = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
...
}
```

I wanted to move this code out to another class, but when I did that I get this error that intellij reports:

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException

public class SomeUtil {

  public String readFromInput(ServletInputStream is) {

    return CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
  }

}
```

Does the servlet doPost somewhere handle this exception that I can't see?

Comment: Could you try the constructor which take a Charset ? (aka: `Charset.forName("utf-8")`)

Comment: Why does the same code work in the doPost of my servlet?

Comment: What is the class that it is currently in? Are you extending from some Servlet class that already throws a more generic exception (like IOException)?

Comment: I don't know why, I can only guess with so much information. Could you also post the full stacktrace to see if it's in InputStreamReader ? Oh, and the exception is normally thrown when an encoding is not found (here, the first guess would be UTF-8 but that's not it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doPost()` method declares `throws ServletException, IOException` which covers for the `throws UnsupportedEncodingException` in the **InputStreamReader** constructor you are using.

In your `readFromInput()` method, you could declare a `throws` clause as well or surround that line in a *try-catch* block. To avoid the `UnsupportedEncodingException`, use the constructor that accepts a **Charset** object and just pass in the standard [UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8).